# insert row in wordpress table with wpdb class

Tags: post, insert, wordpress

I'm working on this little plugin that enables a user to submit a post on my website.

```
if (!isset($wpdb))
    $wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'posts',
    array(
        'post_title' => 'testerrrr',
        'post_author' => '1',
        'post_content' => 'geen content aja',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    )
);
```

The above code isn't adding a new row to the table. (I also tried with $wpdb->wp_posts) And it doesn't give me an error neither (error reporting is turned on though)
Are there maybe other fields that I'm obliged to use in the array, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using `wp_insert_post()` - check the codex, try it out,  and come back if you're still having problems :) - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: I found that function few minutes after I posted this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TheDeadMedic stated, this can be achieved with wp_inser_post();

Comment: wp_insert_post(); - you are missing a T, sir